# Как передать текст из Java кода в WebView?

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Есть `WebView`, он грузит страницу html (из папки assets в проекте) в которой есть форма с textarea...

Как сделать чтоб при вызове метода `setText("text");` в `MainActivity` в мою форму `textarea` вставлялся текст из метода `setText("text");`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Определить функцию в JS:

   ```
   function callFromActivity(msg){
          // здесь строка, переданная из Java
   }
   ```
2. В Java части вызвать `webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromActivity(\"Привет\")");`

В JS методе `callFromActivity` делайте с текстом, что душе угодно.

Comment: Ваш пример не роботает...

Comment: Какая ошибка? JS у WebView включили?

Comment: Я думаю это через то что страница (index.html) в папке assets а не на сервере... есть другой способ?

Comment: Ошибки нет.. просто не втавляет текст.. js включен

Comment: @Вадим покажите код вашей `index.html`. Для начала, выведите `msg` в методе `callFromActivity`: `alert(msg);` там напишите.

Comment: Ну вот: `<script>function callFromActivity(msg){alert(msg);}</script>` пожалуйста...